# Is this a "decent" encryption approach?

Tags: android, encryption

I have an android app that connects to a back-end rails app. I want to encrypt the data I'm sending in-between devices and the server. I'm using basic encryption with a secret key. The key is not really that secret since I'm storing it on the apk and, as so, it's easily ex-tractable using reverse-engineering and apk decompiling techniques.

What I've come up with is generating a secret key based on the user's password. Key's required to be of a fixed length, and seeing how forcing users to use super-long passwords it's not an option, what I'm doing is adding characters (basically the ones I was using in my old hard-coded key) so the string (password + characters) has the required length. I'm then encrypting all the parameters (I'm using a JSON for server-client communication) except the username (which technically shouldn't be encrypted so it's not a big deal). When the JSON request reaches the server, I'm using the username parameter to grab the user's password from the database (server-based) and then constructing the key I need to "de-encrypt/ encrypt" the data I'm receiving/sending. This way, the key is always the same between Server/Client but it's unique for every user and that way I don't have to store an easy-to-get, hardcoded key in my APK. Also, the password is not stored in the device, the users are required to enter the password every time they want to log into the server.

What I want to know is, can this approach be considered "decently secured"?

Comment: Are the usernames unique?  If not, using the username to retrieve the password will cause issues if you have multiple instances of the same use name.  Also, what happens if a user changes their password?  Do you then re-encrypt all the data (assuming its encrypted at rest, that is)?

Comment: Yeah, usernames are unique.

Comment: Why not just use https?

Comment: @Tim , users are handled in the server-side only. User's are not allowed to change their password via the app.

Comment: @Nasch , wouldn't that require the server to be running under https? I cannot guarantee the back-end will be running on an https-based server.

Comment: Are you on a hosting platform or something that doesn't let you do https?  It sounds like you have control over the server since you're talking about making changes there.

Comment: @Nasch, I have control over the web-app deployment, not so much over the platform in which it'd be based on.

Comment: Gotcha.  You should probably already be hashing the passwords with SHA-512 or something like that, and I would think you could use that as a key to encrypt the payload.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem) You use the public key (stored in app) to encrypt data, then the server use the private key (stored on server) to decrypt data. Using RSA you can't uncrypt packet using public key, only crypt it. So it's secure. You should create a keypair (or keyset) for each client.

Comment: That would prevent MITM attacks I think, but an attacker could get the public key and send a request, and the server wouldn't know it was from an attacker.  Whether that's a problem is up to the OP.

Comment: If authenticity is a problem then the request should be signed with the private key.

Comment: Use the public key crypto to establish a symmetric key crypto session that can be used to pass secrets like the username/password for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach in security point of view looks fine, however in user experience point of view, could be of low quality. Also for generating fixed length strings from user's password you can use hash functions.

Another approach is retrieving the encryption keys at run time and storing them in [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). Accessing Android Keystore is far more difficult for attackers to access the keys. Also this approach doesn't require users to enter their passwords each time they use the app. However this approach is subject to [MitM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) when you're exchanging the symmetric key for the first time. To address this problem you should first use asymmetric cryptography schemes to securely exchange the symmetric key, then you can always use the key stored in the keystore.

Note that you shouldn't use asymmetric cypto to encrypt/decrypt your network traffic, because asymmetric methods are usually processor-intensive and kill the battery especially for mobile devices.

However in my opinion the best approach is using TLS solution. In TLS for agreeing on a pre-shared key (i.e. symmetric key), RSA algorithm is used then all traffics are encrypted/decrypted using symmetric algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a password-based key derivation algorithm if you wanted:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

The thing to think about, though, is whether your key rotation schedule will automatically be the same as your password rotation schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the client and server to have the same symmetric key based on some "password", correct? Why not just derive the key from the password on each end.

The client would prompt for the password, and then create good random salt (unique for each connection), and using a high number of iterations, generate a secure key.

The client then sends the salt and iteration count in the clear to the server. The server looks up its copy of the password (assuming that you are storing the password, and not a hash), and with the salt and iterations, generates the matching symmetric key.

The unique salt per connection makes it difficult to prepare a set of pre-derived keys to try, and the high iteration count incurs a huge time cost to perform a dictionary attack against the server (i.e. trying a hugh number of passwords).